# Modifying metabox custom field through myphpadmin causing wordpress to show blank

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, meta-boxes

so basically on my wordpress site, i link images and i recently changed my image domain name, so i went into phpmyadmin and typed:

`` UPDATE `wp_postmeta` SET `meta_value` = replace(meta_value, 'old-domain.com', 'new-domain.com') ``

and my mysql/phpmyadmin, its all updated to the new  domain, but on wordpress, the custom field hasnt picked up the new details and is left blank.

this is my array for the custom field:

````
        'title'  => 'Embed Image',
        'pages' => array( 'post' ),
        'tabs'      => array(
            'input-version' => array(
                'label' => 'Input Version',
                'icon'  => 'dashicons-admin-customizer',
        ),
        'tab_style' => 'default',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'id'     => 'ab_embedgroup',
                'type'   => 'group',
                'clone'  => true,
                'sort_clone'  => true,
                'save_state' => true,
                'desc' => '<b style="color:red;">Insert embed code</b>',
                'tab'  => 'input-version',
                'fields' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'  => 'Host Name',
                        'id'    => 'ab_hostname',
                        'type'  => 'text',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name'   => 'IMEmbed',
                        'id'     => 'ab_embed',
                        'type'   => 'textarea',
                        'sanitize_callback' => 'none',```

cleared cache, restarted VPS, tried it all, just cant understand why it wont pick it up.
am i editing it incorrectly? Cant do it one by one because its a few thousand images.
````

Comment: You should use the WP-CLI instead of find/replace, since some items will be in serialized arrays. https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Comment: _"and is left blank"_ - It's not a good idea to do a manual replace in the postmeta table. WP tends to store data serialized (using PHP's serialize()). If you replace strings in serialized data with a string of a different length, it will be corrupted and PHP won't be able to unserialize it again.

Comment: yeah, might try wpcli but i thought itd be easier to edit that way